# Referring to images in blog in layout neutral way?

Tags: single-word-requests

I write blog posts where I need to refer to product images without knowing exactly where they are (layout wise) in relation to the text I write, meaning that the images might be above, below, or to the side of the text.

Is there a single word I can use as a label that makes it clear that the text which follows is regarding the image(s) in the post? How about *depicted* or *products*?

Comment: You may find the folks over on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ may be able to help if there is a specific term used in User Interface design

Answer (score 3):

Why not label them explicitly - Figure 1, Figure 2, etc? Then refer to them by label, e.g. "Figure 1 shows a widget." No room for confusion then!

Comment: Because this isn't a research paper so it doesn't make sense stylistically.

Comment: Images are numbered in other kinds of documents besides research papers. Also, they could be labelled in an informal way. Depending on the context, something like "Snapshot 1" or "Photo 1" might work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like, "... the products/items/objects/[etc.] illustrated in this blog ..."

Answer (score 0):

If you quote them in the order they are layout wise, you could use 'respectively'

Comment: Sorry, but I need a specific label because there's other text in a particular blog post that's not related to the images.

Comment: An example The images described respectively from left to right as 'image1..., image 2... or top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

- The products **as shown** on the website...
- The various products **pictured**....
- The products **represented** on this page...
- The aforementioned products **as seen**...
- The numerous products and **whose images** in the blog...
- The choice of products **on view**...